# Most recent terra package for R will not compile

Tags: r, terra

I am trying to install the newest version of the terra package, but I keep getting the following errors:

```
no DLL was created
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'terra'
* removing 'C:/Users/ruben/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2/terra'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/ruben/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2/terra'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘terra’ had non-zero exit status
```

I don't know if this is my fault or if there is something not right with the package or compiler.  Any help on this would be great.

Comment: There should be more details about the compilation error just before the text that you've posted.

Answer (score 1):

To install the CRAN version from source, you need to install the system dependencies (on OSX and Linux) or, on windows, have the *current version* of Rtools installed.

On OSX and Windows, you can choose to *not* install from source. To get the latest released version you would have to wait a couple of days until CRAN has a compiled ("binary") version available for your R version and operating system.

Another way to use a recent version of "terra" on windows is to get the development version from the R-universe:

```
install.packages('terra', repos='https://rspatial.r-universe.dev')
```

For more info on installation go the [terra github site](https://github.com/rspatial/terra/)

Comment: I have the current Rtools version, al the dependencies, etc.  That is why it is so strange it did not work right.  Anyway, I'll just wait for the compiled version.

Comment: It would help if you included all the console output. From what you show we know it went wrong, but there is no way to tell why.